# How to proxy a request from a client to an Apache Pulsar broker?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, proxy, apache-pulsar

I'm attempting to connect a client running in a Kubernetes cluster to an Apache Pulsar cluster hosted by [StreamNative](https://streamnative.io/). Specifically, I'm attempting to use the [logstash-input-pulsar Plugin](https://github.com/streamnative/logstash-input-pulsar), which doesn't support auth. One option is to fork logstash-input-pulsar and add authentication; however, a more general option would be create a proxy between logstash and pulsar, where the proxy is able to handle authentication. (For example, the proxy could be a sidecar on the kubernetes pod where logstash is running.) I looked into using the [Pulsar Proxy](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/administration-proxy/); however, this proxy is intended to run on the same Kubernetes cluster as the Pulsar broker(s). If the Pulsar client was using the HTTP protocol, I could set up nginx as a proxy between the client and broker, and nginx could add the appropriate auth - a header, for example. Pulsar, however, uses its own protocol over TCP. Would there still be a way to have a proxy that handles adding auth between the pulsar client and broker?